# A better word than "Response"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am writing a logline for a story which deals with the global immigration crisis and the Catholic Church's response to it. I think the word *response* here would have a negative connotation when the story talks about the help the church is giving stranded and helpless migrants.

Comment: why do you think _response_ has a negative connotation?

Comment: I agree that _response_ is neutral. Another option would be _reaction_.

Comment: No "better" word can be given unless you give more details about what's wrong with *response*. (Why you think it's negative.) Without that, any answers here can only be random synonyms (that you may or may not also think are negative.)

Answer (score 2):

You could instead use `Addressed`.

> The Catholic church addressed the issue of *x* by *y*

But I do not think `response` has any negative implications in this context.

Answer (score 2):

'Response' is, indeed, neutral so it requires some *additional information.*

> The Catholic Church's **initiative**, in response to the issue, was ...

Definitions of 'initiative' :

> Initiative - a new plan or process to achieve something or solve a problem:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/initiative)

> That which initiates, begins, or originates; the first step in some process or enterprise; hence the act, or action, of initiating or taking the first step or lead; beginning, commencement, origination.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/96070?rskey=RzaozU&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)